# Handle external Entities and Stylesheet in Sax Parser (XML)

Tags: java, xml, security, saxparser

I want to ignore external entities and external stylesheets (eg. `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="......."?>`).

I know I have to set `XMLReader` property to ignore external entities but I don't know how to ignore stylesheets...

```
import org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
//...
final XMLReader parser = new SAXParser();

// Ignore entities
parser.setProperty("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);

//  IS CORRECT???
parser.setProperty("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
```

There are more properties to set to avoid external entities and stylesheet?
How Can I understand if there are external entities o stylesheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working for me:

```
public class SaxParser extends DefaultHandler
    implements ContentHandler, DTDHandler, EntityResolver{

public transient static final String STYLE_SHEET_TAG = "xml-stylesheet";
public transient static final String EXTERNAL_ENTITY = "ExternalEntity";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SaxParser().execute();
}

public void execute() {
    String pathFileXml = "test/XML.xml";

    final XMLReader parser = new SAXParser();
    parser.setContentHandler(this);
    parser.setDTDHandler(this);
    parser.setEntityResolver(this);

    try {
        parser.parse(pathFileXml);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {

        if (SaxParser.STYLE_SHEET_TAG.equals(e.getMessage())
                || SaxParser.EXTERNAL_ENTITY.equals(e.getMessage())) {

            System.out.println("CATCH ERRORE");
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("OK");
}

@Override
public void processingInstruction(String target, String data)
        throws SAXException {
    System.out.println("Processing Instruction");
    System.out.println("PI=> target: " + target + ", data: " + data);

    if (STYLE_SHEET_TAG.equalsIgnoreCase(target.trim())) {
        throw new SAXException(STYLE_SHEET_TAG);
    }
    return;
}
    @Override
    public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId)
        throws IOException, SAXException {

    System.out.println("publicId: " + publicId + ", systemId: " + systemId);
    throw new SAXException(SaxParser.EXTERNAL_ENTITY);


}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [external stylesheet declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-stylesheet/) is a standard [processing instruction](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi).

You can ignore processing instructions by *not* implementing the handler method:

```
void processingInstruction(java.lang.String target, java.lang.String data) {}
```

in your SAX handler.

Comment: Is ignore entities: `parser.setProperty("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);` correct?

Comment: It seems to be, but have to check if the parser you use supports it. Not all parsers support all features. It's implementation dependent.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html#external-general-entities) that would be the correct way to set the property.